# OpenID/OAuth Reverse Proxy

Tags: oauth, openid, reverse-proxy

I have a bunch of existing web applications that use either Windows authentication, or username/password authentication.

Instead of asking users to keep track of usernames/passwords and Windows credentails (since these applications will be web accessible), I'd like to just use an OpenID. But I'd rather not re-write all of the applications to use OpenID.

I'm wondering if there is a reverse proxy that will allow them to log in via OpenID, and then map the OpenID to Windows/username credentials, and reverse proxy to the target web application?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use CAS, and apache has a cas module which can work for you